Only one certificate added to CertPath in Java
First off, I'm a beginner in both Java and Data security.
I have this Java code:
public static CertPath createCertPath(X509Certificate certificate, Set<TrustAnchor> trustAnchors)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException, CertPathBuilderException, CertStoreException {

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    CertStore certStore = CertStoreCreator.createCertStore(certificate, trustAnchors); // Verificado

    // Get CertPathParameters using the previous function
    CertPathParameters certPathParameters = getCertPathParameters(certificate, trustAnchors);

        /*
        // Add the CertStore to the PKIX parameters
        if (certPathParameters instanceof PKIXBuilderParameters) {
            ((PKIXBuilderParameters) certPathParameters).addCertStore(certStore);
            System.out.println("CertStore adicionado aos parâmetros PKIX.");
        }
        //System.out.println(certPathParameters);
        */
    CertStore intermediate = CertStore.getInstance("Collection", new CollectionCertStoreParameters(Arrays.asList(certStore)));
    ((PKIXBuilderParameters) certPathParameters).addCertStore(intermediate);

    try {
        CertPathBuilder certPathBuilder = CertPathBuilder.getInstance("PKIX", "BC");
        CertPathBuilderResult result = certPathBuilder.build(certPathParameters);
        CertPath certPath = result.getCertPath();

        // Imprimir todos os certificados no CertPath resultante
        System.out.println("Certificados no CertPath:");
        for (Certificate cert : certPath.getCertificates()) {
            System.out.println(((X509Certificate) cert).getSubjectX500Principal());
        }
        return certPath;

    } catch (CertPathBuilderException e) {
        System.out.println("ERRO: Não foi possível construir o CertPath: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERRO inesperado: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Cria os parâmetros para a construção do caminho de certificação
 *
 * @param certificate  O certificado final do caminho de certificação
 * @param trustAnchors As possíveis âncoras de confiança para o caminho de certificação
 * @return Os parâmetros para a construção do caminho de certificação
 * @see CertPathCreator#createCertPath(X509Certificate, Set)
 */
@ImplementMe
public static CertPathParameters getCertPathParameters(X509Certificate certificate,
                                                       Set<TrustAnchor> trustAnchors)
        throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

    // Código adaptado da resposta de:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671487/generate-x509certificate-certpath-in-java

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());


    // Define o certificado final
    X509CertSelector certSelector = new X509CertSelector();
    certSelector.setCertificate(certificate);

    // Cria os parametros
    PKIXBuilderParameters pkixParams = new PKIXBuilderParameters(trustAnchors, certSelector);

    pkixParams.setRevocationEnabled(false);

    return pkixParams;
}

The certificates are added correctly to the certStore, but when I check the certificates inside the certPath, there's only the end certificate, no other certificate has been added, I can't figure out why.
I expected a certPath with all the certificates in the trust chain, but I only get the final one on the trust chain.
